# Snowflake External Tables Refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here are the below steps I followed for creating the external table in a snowflake using the documentation

1. Create a Stage in AWS
2. Create External Tables and here is the below ddl statement

   ```
     **CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE
           PROD_EXT_TABLE
           WITH LOCATION=@my_stage
           REFRESH_ON_CREATE=TRUE
           FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV SKIP_HEADER=1)**
   ```
3. I can query the data using the select statement and I can do the Manual refresh on the table using the below Statement

   ```
     **ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE IF EXISTS PROD_EXT_TABLE REFRESH**
   ```

Now I want to do the automatic refresh of the external table whenever we place the file or removes the file in the external stage.

The documentation says that we can configure with SQS and the same SQL URL can be obtained under the notification channel of the External table and then use the below statement

show external tables, the notification channel is empty for the external tables.

Please do let me know if I miss anything.
[image]

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm wondering if the notification channel is always null

Comment: Have you done any ownership changes on this table? If that's the case try doing an **alter external table <table_name> set auto_refresh=true;**

Comment: Di you find the answer for this?